# Executing an EXE file in WiX

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

I try to execute an EXE file from an MSI file in WiX, but I got 1603 error when doing InitializeSetup.

```
Action ended 12:09:54: InstallValidate. Return value 1.
Action start 12:09:54: InstallInitialize.
Action ended 12:09:54: InstallInitialize. Return value 3.
Action ended 12:09:54: INSTALL. Return value 3.
```

What is wrong in this WiX Script?

```
 <Product Name='something' Id='11934d63-12d1-4792-829e-046de3bb987e'
  UpgradeCode='{a101616a-365c-44a7-bfcb-fafb356c2ea1}'
  Language='1033' Version='8.3.4' Manufacturer='something2'>

    <Package Id='*' InstallerVersion='200' Compressed='yes' />

    <Binary Id="Instalator.exe" SourceFile="d:\Instalator.exe"/>
    <CustomAction Id="LaunchFile" BinaryKey="Instalator.exe" ExeCommand="" Execute='deferred' Return='asyncNoWait' Impersonate='no'/>
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action='LaunchFile' Before='InstallFinalize'/>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
 </Product>
```

I don't know why, but when I add:

```
<Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
        <Component Id='MainExecutable' Guid='1193cd63-12d1-4792-829e-046de3bb987e'>
        </Component>
</Directory>

<Feature Id='Complete' Level='1'>
  <ComponentRef Id='MainExecutable' />
</Feature>
```

after Package node -> then it works fine. I need to figure out why...

Comment: May I ask what "instalator.exe" does?  You might be reinventing the wheel here. http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/8/17/Zataoca-Custom-actions-are-generally-an-admission-of-failure

Comment: Instalator.exe is an installer in Inno Setup. I just need msi.

Comment: There is not much point doing this. You will be bypassing a lot of the advantages that you gain by using msi and wix. I would think the reason that adding the component worked, was due to the fact that as AFAIK a feature-less msi is invalid. I personally would take the time to convert the InnoSetup into wix, it'll be much better in the long-run.

Comment: Ah, you are writing a "fake" MSI.  I wouldn't do that. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robmen/archive/2006/02/01/521809.aspx

Comment: Yes I think that is bad idea, but I think too it's bad idea to use MSI. User want user must have. I don't have time to do it right. Maybe in next release. Thanks for answering me.

Comment: I think 1603 error has nothing to do with your exe file. It mainly because there must be at least one Directory and component in your product.

Comment: We had this issue as well. Initially we had `<Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>` in Product.wxs (our main .wxs file) and `<DirectoryRef Id='TARGETDIR'>` in a <File.wxs> fragment. When we switched the two tags so that `<Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>` was in `<File.wxs>` and `<DirectoryRef Id='TARGETDIR'>` was in the Product.wxs, the error went away. Curious...

Answer (score 5):

I have some other concerns about what you are doing here, but if you really need to go out of process to an EXE to complete your install, then I'd suggest using the [Quiet Execution Custom Action](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/qtexec.htm).

You should know though that this isn't a good practice for a number of reasons.  1) It's not declarative, 2) it doesn't support rollbacks. There are others but those are the biggest IMO.

BTW, WiX isn't "scripting".  Understand that and you'll understand why not to call EXE's.

Comment: I have a file that has compressed dependencies for my project. Executing that file puts those dependencies in the directory it is in.  Is this also considered bad practice? what do you suggest as an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are running the exe as a deferred action, it runs in the context of the SYSTEM account. This error is due to the system account not having the required permissions on the file system http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834484.

It is possible to get around this using PowerShell to execute the exe using the -RunAs switch, but this is a bit nasty. It really all depends exactly what you are doing in the exe as to the best course of action. I'm with Mr. Painter, using an EXE should be the last resort.

Another option is to move the exe setup code so that it runs the first time the user runs the app.

Answer (score 0):

Important note for **WIX**, After completion of all application installation then the .sql file or database files runs through `wix` or `wpf` or `winform` application.